# localstorage is not defined in Next js to use in useReducer

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, use-reducer

I'm having a problem accessing to localstorage in third argument of useReducer as lazy-initial to get shopping cart items from localstorage. Can anyone help with with this please? I need to access localstorage so that shopping cart which is 'MedicineToBuy' remain the same after page reload.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import { cartReducer } from 'reducers/CartReducers'

export const CartStates = createContext()

export const CartProvider = props => {
  
  const [cartVisibile, setCartVisible] = useState(false)
  const [medicineToBuy, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, [],function(){
    const storageData = localStorage.getItem('Cart');
    return storageData ? JSON.parse(storageData) : [];
  })

  useEffect( () => {
    localStorage.setItem('Cart', JSON.stringify(medicineToBuy))
  }, [medicineToBuy] )

  const value = {
    visibility: [cartVisibile, setCartVisible],
    itemsInCart: [medicineToBuy],
    dispatch: dispatch,
  }

  return <CartStates.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</CartStates.Provider>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your componentent is most likely rendered server side where **window** is not available, therefore local storage or any other browser APIs cannot be used.

You could check if *window* is defined before using local storage:

```
  const [medicineToBuy, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, [],function(){
    const storageData = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('Cart') : null;
    return storageData ? JSON.parse(storageData) : [];
  })
```

You could extract this into a re-usable variable and use it everywhere you need to access a browser API:

```
export const IS_CLIENT = typeof window !== 'undeinfed';
```

**Important:** this will work only when the code runs **client side**.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer just solved the issue perfectly.